# RequiredIf Conditional Validation in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i was reading a small code for RequiredIf Conditional Validation in MVC3 and the code as follows.

```
string depProp = context.Controller.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(this.DependentProperty);

public class Person
{
       [RequiredIf("Address.Country", "USA", ErrorMessage = "SSN required for US citizens.")]
       [RegularExpression(@"^\d{9,9}$", ErrorMessage = "Numbers only please.")]
       public string SSN { get; set; }
       public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

1) first of all i like to know at all any in-built attribute called `RequiredIf` is available in mvc 3 ?

2) if not then how we can create this attribute which will emit right js at client end which show the validation message.

3) what is the meaning of this below line

```
string depProp = context.Controller.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(this.DependentProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're searching for Simon Ince's implementation of `RequiredIf` attribute.

The attribute implementation could be found at [Conditional Validation in MVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/04/conditional-validation-in-mvc.aspx).

The js-side described at [Adding Client-Side Script to an MVC Conditional Validator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/11/adding-client-side-script-to-an-mvc-conditional-validator.aspx).